# JavaScript Code is not always working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am working with Fusionchart XT and it should generate a javaScript, which generates a chart.

This is the first script, which is working:

```
    <!-- Using ASP.NET FusionCharts Wrapper and JavaScript rendering --><!-- START Script Block for Chart Kund_Sprache -->
<div id='Kund_Sprache_div' >
Chart...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
FusionCharts && FusionCharts.ready(function () {
if (FusionCharts("Kund_Sprache") ) FusionCharts("Kund_Sprache").dispose();
var chart_Kund_Sprache = new FusionCharts({
"width" : "50%", 
"height" : "100%      ", 
"id" : "Kund_Sprache", 
"type" : "Pie2D", 
"dataSource" : "<chart logoURL='coins.png' caption='Sprache' showvalues='1' showlabels='0' showlegend='1' legendborder='0' legendposition='right' theme='flat'><set label='DE' value='239'/><set label='FR' value='50'/><set label='IT' value='60'/><set label='EN' value=70'/></chart>", 
"dataFormat" : "xml", 
"renderAt" : "Kund_Sprache_div", 
}).render();
});
</script>
<!-- END Script Block for Chart Kund_Sprache -->
```

And then I've got the second one, which is not working and only displays "Chart...":

```
    <!-- Using ASP.NET FusionCharts Wrapper and JavaScript rendering --><!-- START Script Block for Chart Kund -->
<div id='Kund_div' >
Chart...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
FusionCharts && FusionCharts.ready(function () {
if (FusionCharts("Kund") ) FusionCharts("Kund").dispose();
var chart_Kund = new FusionCharts({
"width" : "50%", 
"height" : "100%", 
"id" : "Kund", 
"type" : "Pie2D", 
"dataSource" : "<chart showvalues='1' caption='Kund' showlabels='0' showlegend='1' legendborder='0' legendposition='right' theme='flat'><set label='1 St' value='26'/><set label='2 St' value='41'/><set label='3 St' value='9'/></chart>", 
"dataFormat" : "xml", 
"renderAt" : "Kund_div", 
}).render();
});
</script>
<!-- END Script Block for Chart Kund -->
```

Does anyone see a diffrence? Or why is the javascript not executed in the second one? (it only displays the first div)

Comment: Maybe a [diff tool](https://www.diffchecker.com/v0vfr7up) helps.

Comment: logoURL is missing in the second code on the line with dataSource: "<chart..."

Comment: I don't know if this could fix the problem,but maybe if you delete the white spaces in the percentage value in "height" : "100%      "

Comment: @userDEV This doesn't need to be there but you can write it if you want.

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta Yes this is different, but the top one is working.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any error logged. If not try step debugging to see if the code is executing as intended. You should also remove the 'comma' after the last attribute `renderAt`.

Comment: @pallabB It says: runtime error in JavaScript: "FusionChart" is undefined. The comma after the last attribute gets generated automatically, so I can't change that.

Comment: @aha364636, Good that you figured it out. :) Always cross check your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to link the FusionChart script inside the head tag:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
     <script src="/Fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/Fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.flat.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```